# Adding sound effects to game using sdl2?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I was working on a game and needed to mix sound effects into BGM, using lib SDL2. Say I was working ONLY with wav files, would the basic SDL2 library serve it well, or I should install the adding-on library SDL_mixer ?

Comment: I wanted to look up some example code to play a simple sound effect before installing SDL_mixer. After looking at the wiki I deceded not to take my chances and just install mixer.

If someone wants to take a look themself:
http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_OpenAudioDevice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should plan on using SDL2-mixer if you want to use compressed sound files. Wav are good for little sound effects, but if you plan on playing some background music too, you will need to use compressed sound file, because a Wav file for a 3 minutes sound is really big.

Like they said on their website : "SDL_mixer is a sample multi-channel audio mixer library." But, if you want only to play with wav files only, SDL2 can do it as well. Personally, I'll go with sdl2-mixer.

Comment: Does SDL_mixer support loading from non-wav? It was doing only mixing last time i've checked.

Comment: "It supports any number of simultaneously playing channels of 16 bit stereo audio, plus a single channel of music, mixed by the popular FLAC, MikMod MOD, Timidity MIDI, Ogg Vorbis, and SMPEG MP3 libraries."    from http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/

Comment: Thanks. `LoadWAV` sort of deceived me, combined with lack of specified formats support when i've actually used it.

Comment: Yeah I have gone my way to mixer:) Thanks!